# Pressure sensitive stylus for Lenovo Edge

Tags: stylus

I just got a Lenovo Edge 15, and was wondering if there were any styluses that would work for it. I've seen Thinkpad styluses for very little and would get one of those if they work. I also tried a Wacom Bamboo stylus but it didn't work.